# How to align divs horizontally in a consistent way?

Tags: html, css

In my HTML, I want to align 8 colored divs horizontally separated by constant space. 
I have a `<table>` as container for these divs. The size is specified in percent(%) instead of pixels(px) for scaling.

When a user resizes the window the divs also get resized but not in equal proportion (i.e. height!=width) and results in looking like a rectangle rather than a square. I'd like to align these divs in such a way that when a user resizes the window the divs also get resized in equal proportion, and also retain their square shape.

Comment: Can I see the actual HTML and CSS?

Comment: It would be good to go back through and accept answers to questions that you've asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pure HTML/CSS solution to scaling divs in a manner which maintains their proportions - you'll need to use some scripting. See a JQuery solution you could use here: [Scale a div to fit in window but preserve aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311068/scale-a-div-to-fit-in-window-but-preserve-aspect-ratio)

Comment: I'm not voting you down because I'm not sure exactly what you meant in that statement, but if you meant that there is no way to preserve a div's aspect ratio using pure HTML/CSS, you are mistaken. See the two approaches I presented in the page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a transparent square GIF image (1×1px is enough) with `width: 100%` into each block. The dimensions of the image and its container will be maintained constant automatically regardless of particular calculated pixel value of `width: 100%`.