# lazy load plugin throwing Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, referenceerror

i am using http://davidwalsh.name/lazyload-plugin when i run it giving a error in console as "Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined".
i added code as below

```
<script src="lazyload/Source/LazyLoad.js"></script>
```

then downside

```
    <script>
/* do it! */
window.addEvent("domready",function() {
    var lazyloader = new LazyLoad();
});
</script>
```

and in body for images i am using as below.

```
<img alt=\"\" src=\"lazyload/Assets/blank.gif\" data-src=\"{$v['image_path']}\" style=width:auto;height:200px;max-height:200px>
```

where $v['image_path'] is dynamic.
What is the problem causing that error please help me.

Comment: add mootools  lib  file in your page https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools.js

Answer (score 1):

you are missing mootools library . add mootools library above LazyLoad.js

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/wbgk94pa/1/)

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools.js"></script>
 <script src="lazyload/Source/LazyLoad.js"></script>


 <script>
   /* do it! */
    window.addEvent("domready",function() {
      var lazyloader = new LazyLoad();
    });
</script>
```

HTML  . in put same image path for src and data-src .

```
<img alt=\"\" src=\"{$v['image_path']}\" data-src=\"{$v['image_path']}\" style=width:auto;height:200px;max-height:200px>
```

Comment: why mootools? is this plugin defend upon mootools?

Comment: as per your link to plugin it work on mootools library

Comment: after adding mootools. no images are getting displayed.

Comment: @shridhar check demo in my answer . its same code copy from  davidwalsh.name/js/lazyload  and it works . i have added mootools library  and copy code from davidwalsh.name/js/lazyload and its working .

Comment: alos check your lazyload/Source/LazyLoad.js path and  use img as i update in my answer

Comment: its working in jfiddle but in my localhost its not working. might other scripts are getting clash.

Comment: If you have jquery library in your page then it will clash or I think you are miss to add any js file ?? Copy code from my fiddle and check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096300/combining-lazyload-and-jquery-masonry this is the problem.