# Scale a div length-wise; preserve aspect ratio

Tags: html, aspect-ratio

SO: I've spent a number of hours tackling this design problem but can't seem to find a precise answer. I'm attempting to scale a div to fit a designated height but constrain its aspect ratio. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/ks2jH/121/

Based on my research, the discussion has *sort of* been had all over the place, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311068/scale-a-div-to-fit-in-window-but-preserve-aspect-ratio). Trouble is, the div only resizes & constrains based on the browser's width, and not its height.

The two closest solutions I found work for width: 
(1) use the :after pseudo-class http://jsfiddle.net/ks2jH/89/, or
(2) use a blank/transparent png [http://jsfiddle.net/ks2jH/94/].

The idea, of course, is to achieve the same thing *without specifying* a width because it auto adjusts based on the height.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it, using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/5TETn/210/

I was able to modify an aspect ratio script [see:http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/5TETn/8] by [Mottie over at GitHub](https://github.com/Mottie) to achieve what CSS alone couldn't. Much gratitude, kind sir.