# Is there a way to make background image auto width, full height, height scroll, no width scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place a picture to background thus it was full screen, the width of image should change to body width and no horizontal scroll. On the other hand, I want height be with ratio to width (no distortion) and had vertical scroll.
I am now doing:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body
{
    background-color: #767676;

}
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('back.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 0;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

But it shrink height and no scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not setting image `background` in `body`?

```
body {
    background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle ilustrating the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/Kqkyb/2/

**EDIT**:
I'm not sure if I got the *scroll* idea from your question correctly but for now I changed it to `fixed` so the image will always stay at the top of the viewport no matter where the page is scrolled to.
**EDIT2**:
Another update. I examined your CSS more precisely and noticed that you wanted the image to be positioned in center - both in vertical and horizontal axis. I corrected it in the code as well as in the fiddle.

Comment: This is not what I want actually. My whole page is just this image and I want to scroll it vertically.

Comment: Can you prepare an example of what you're trying to achieve? A similar website or an image illustrating the effect?

Comment: I do not copy it, so I have no idea where to find example. Sorry. It can be any image.

Comment: But I got some idea: I will add an extra div with 1px width and height that will calculate everytime when brouser is resized.

Comment: Now I've got completely confused.

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to explan. I solved it:
$("#wrapper").css({'height':($("body").width() * 462 / 694 +'px')});

462 / 694 - is ratio of my image. So now when brouser resize image (i.e. width), I got new width, calculate height and make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Restless night and, finally, i've solved exactly the same trouble. I combined two ideas:

1. [Scale a div to fit in window but preserve aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311068/scale-a-div-to-fit-in-window-but-preserve-aspect-ratio)
2. and well-known techniques, i mean first one from here
   http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

HTML

```
<div class='image'>
     <div class="content"></div>
<div>
```

and CSS

```
.image{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%; 
}
.image::after {
  padding-top: 66.66%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('../img/image.png');
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;  /* follow the parent's edges */
```

Important!

```
padding-top: 66.66%;
```

Percentage of containing block width(!). It depends of 
    aspect ratio of your image. I used imagemap 1920x1280, so 1280 / 1920 = 0.6666666.
The result is absolutely responsive and scales to any resolution. And the main thing - vertical scroll appears!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#wrapper").css({'height':($("body").width() * 462 / 694 +'px')});
```

462 / 694 - is ratio of my image. So now when brouser resize image (i.e. width), I got new width, calculate height and make it work.

But I suppose there must be some css solution.