# Maintain aspect ratio of div but fill screen width and height in CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I have a site to put together that has a fixed aspect ratio of approximately `16:9` landscape, like a video.

I want to have it centred and expand to fill the available width, and the available height, but never to grow larger on either side.

**For example:**

1. A tall and thin page would have the content stretching the full width while maintaining a proportional height.
2. A short wide page would have the content stretching the full height, with a proportional width.

---

There are two methods I've been looking at:

1. Use an image with the right aspect ratio to expand a container `div`, but I couldn't get it to behave the same way across major browsers.
2. Setting a proportional bottom padding, but that only works relatively to the width and ignores the height. It just keeps getting bigger with the width and displays vertical scroll bars.

---

I know you could do this with JS quite easily, but I'd like a pure CSS solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design Set container div to `position: relative (default) height: 0 padding-<top/bottom>: H/W*100%`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65864203/8620333

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is now a new CSS property specified to address this: `object-fit`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

The feature is widely supported by now (http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).

Answer (score 332):

Use the new [CSS viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) `vw` and `vh` (viewport width / viewport height)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8VJ38/3/)**

**Resize vertically and horizontally and you'll see that the element will always fill the maximum viewport size without breaking the ratio and without scrollbars!**

### (PURE) CSS

```
div
{
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 56.25vw; /* height:width ratio = 9/16 = .5625  */
    background: pink;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 177.78vh; /* 16/9 = 1.778 */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
  /* 100/56.25 = 1.778 */
  background: pink;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 177.78vh;
  /* 16/9 = 1.778 */
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* vertical center */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* horizontal center */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If you want to use a maximum of say 90% width and height of the viewport: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8VJ38/410/)**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 90vw;
  /* 90% of viewport vidth */
  height: 50.625vw;
  /* ratio = 9/16 * 90 = 50.625 */
  background: pink;
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 160vh;
  /* 16/9 * 90 = 160 */
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Also, browser support is pretty good too: IE9+, FF, Chrome, Safari- [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

Comment: This is a really nice clean solution. I could ideally do with browser support a little further back though. I guess on an older browser you'd just have a minimum width / height and set it to that - if it had scroll bars so be it

Comment: Unfortunately, recent iOS versions [don't support](http://html5please.com/#viewport%20units), or have a broken implementation of viewport units (`vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, `vmax`). However, there is a [workaround](https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587), which uses media queries to target iOS devices.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the 90% solution you have there but my images aren't 16:9 and it's compressing my images vertically. My images are various sizes. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @J82 If your images have different width/height ratios then you'll either need code for each ratio (via separate classes say) OR you'll need to crop your image to suit a particular ratio. If you look at the comments in the fiddle I posted you can easily modify the code to suit the ratio that you need

Comment: the element needs to be div or to have `display:block`

Comment: **vh is not supported on Android 4.3 and below WebView**

Comment: This causes horizontal scrollbars unfortunately :(

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper - i had the prob with scrollbars occasionally appearing too, in my webgl canvas only app (where need to keep 16:9 AR), but it's simple to fix by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the body .. so my body css decl looks like this now: `body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;`}

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. I might add not to forget the "margin: auto" part for anyone out there. This is what can center the content correctly when it shrinks down.

Answer (score 21):

Just reformulating `Danield`'s answer in a LESS mixin, for further usage:

```
// Mixin for ratio dimensions    
.viewportRatio(@x, @y) {
  width: 100vw;
  height: @y * 100vw / @x;
  max-width: @x / @y * 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

div {

  // Force a ratio of 5:1 for all <div>
  .viewportRatio(5, 1);

  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Use a [CSS media query](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) `@media` together with the [CSS viewport units](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) `vw` and `vh` to adapt to the aspect ratio of the viewport. This has the benefit of updating other properties, like `font-size`, too.

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jom2zwpn/1/) demonstrates the fixed aspect ratio for the div, and the text matching its scale exactly.

Initial size is based on full width:

```
div {
  width: 100vw; 
  height: calc(100vw * 9 / 16);

  font-size: 10vw;

  /* align center */
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;

  /* visual indicators */
  background:
    url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAgAUAIABAB1ziv///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAACABQAAAIHhI+pa+EPCwA7) repeat-y center top,
    url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFAACAIABAIodZP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAUAAIAAAIIhI8Zu+nIVgEAOw==) repeat-x left center,
    silver;
}
```

Then, when the viewport is wider than the desired aspect ratio, switch to height as base measure:

```
/* 100 * 16/9 = 177.778 */
@media (min-width: 177.778vh) {
  div {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vh * 16 / 9);

    font-size: calc(10vh * 16 / 9);
  }
}
```

This is very similar in vein to the `max-width` and `max-height` [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593342/2290493) by @Danield, just more flexible.

Answer (score 8):

My original question for this was how to both have an element of a fixed aspect, but to fit that within a specified container exactly, which makes it a little fiddly. If you simply want an individual element to maintain its aspect ratio it is a lot easier.

The best method I've come across is by giving an element zero height and then using percentage padding-bottom to give it height. Percentage padding is always proportional to the width of an element, and not its height, even if its top or bottom padding.

[W3C Padding Properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties)

So utilising that you can give an element a percentage width to sit within a container, and then padding to specify the aspect ratio, or in other terms, the relationship between its width and height.

```
.object {
    width: 80%; /* whatever width here, can be fixed no of pixels etc. */
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.object .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

So in the above example the object takes 80% of the container width, and then its height is 56.25% of that value. If it's width was 160px then the bottom padding, and thus the height would be 90px - a 16:9 aspect.

The slight problem here, which may not be an issue for you, is that there is no natural space inside your new object. If you need to put some text in for example and that text needs to take it's own padding values you need to add a container inside and specify the properties in there.

Also vw and vh units aren't supported on some older browsers, so the accepted answer to my question might not be possible for you and you might have to use something more lo-fi.

Comment: To avoid using extra markup here you can add an element using ::before or ::after and give that element a height of 0 and a padding-bottom relative to the objects width and 0 width of its own. That will have the same effect but with less markup, and will make the full object area useable to put content in without needing a container.

Answer (score 6):

I understand that you asked that you would like a `CSS` specific solution. To keep the aspect ratio, you would need to divide the height by the desired aspect ratio. 16:9 = 1.777777777778.

To get the correct height for the container, you would need to divide the current width by 1.777777777778. Since you can't check the `width` of the container with just `CSS` or divide by a percentage is `CSS`, this is not possible without `JavaScript` (to my knowledge).

I've written a working script that will keep the desired aspect ratio.

**HTML**

```
<div id="aspectRatio"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#aspectRatio { background: #ff6a00; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () {
    //Let's create a function that will scale an element with the desired ratio
    //Specify the element id, desired width, and height
    function keepAspectRatio(id, width, height) {
        var aspectRatioDiv = document.getElementById(id);
        aspectRatioDiv.style.width = window.innerWidth;
        aspectRatioDiv.style.height = (window.innerWidth / (width / height)) + "px";
    }

    //run the function when the window loads
    keepAspectRatio("aspectRatio", 16, 9);

    //run the function every time the window is resized
    window.onresize = function (event) {
        keepAspectRatio("aspectRatio", 16, 9);
    }
}
```

You can use the `function` again if you'd like to display something else with a different ratio by using

```
keepAspectRatio(id, width, height);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doing this in script is relatively straightforward, but I really wanted a CSS based solution. I want a really snappy reliable responsive solution, and I find sometimes resize events in different browsers are a bit laggy. You end up doing your transform a little after the browser resize has occurred, so it doesn't give the best user experience. Want something that renders the moment the browser changes size, hence pure CSS.

Comment: @Henry Gibson The script has been tested in Chrome, FF, IE, Opera, and Safari. All work snappy and are reliable even in older versions of browsers. Every browser fires it's own events. `window.onresize` is fired the moment the browser changes size.

Comment: remember end users don't resize browsers nearly as much as developers do

Answer (score 1):

[Danield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593342/633234) is good, but it can only be used when the div fills the whole viewport, or by using a bit of `calc`, can be used if the width and height of the other content in the viewport is known.

However, by combining the `margin-bottom` trick with the method in the aforementioned answer, the problem can be reduced to just having to know the height of the other content. This is useful if you have a fixed height header, but the width of the sidebar, for example, is not known.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 100px; /* simulating a header */
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: calc(200vh - 200px);
}

section {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

[Here it is in a jsfiddle using scss](https://jsfiddle.net/8zkdudny/), which makes it more obvious where the values come from.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593342/6225838), I wrote this SASS mixin with interpolation (`#{}`) for a youtube video's iframe that is inside a Bootstrap modal dialog:

```
@mixin responsive-modal-wiframe($height: 9, $width: 16.5,
                                $max-w-allowed: 90, $max-h-allowed: 60) {
  $sides-adjustment: 1.7;

  iframe {
    width: #{$width / $height * ($max-h-allowed - $sides-adjustment)}vh;
    height: #{$height / $width * $max-w-allowed}vw;
    max-width: #{$max-w-allowed - $sides-adjustment}vw;
    max-height: #{$max-h-allowed}vh;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-height: 480px) {
    margin-top: 5px;
    .modal-header {
      padding: 5px;
      .modal-title {font-size: 16px}
    }
    .modal-footer {display: none}
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 95vw; // the modal should occupy most of the screen's available space
  text-align: center; // this will center the titles and the iframe

  @include responsive-modal-wiframe();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Video</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/<?= $video_id ?>?rel=0" frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light"
          data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will always display the video **without those black parts** that youtube adds to the iframe when the width or height is not proportional to the video. Notes:

- `$sides-adjustment` is a slight adjustment to compensate a tiny part of these black parts showing up on the sides;
- in very low height devices (< 480px) the standard modal takes up a lot of space, so I decided to:

  1. hide the `.modal-footer`;
  2. adjust the positioning of the `.modal-dialog`;
  3. reduce the sizes of the `.modal-header`.

After a lot of testing, this is working flawlessly for me now.

Answer (score -1):

here a solution based on @Danield solution, that works even within a div.

In that example, I am using Angular but it can quickly move to vanilla JS or another framework.

The main idea is just to move the @Danield solution within an empty iframe and copy the dimensions after iframe window size changes.

That iframe has to fit dimensions with its father element.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aspect-ratio-by-iframe?file=src%2Findex.html

Here a few screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]