# Responsive design: centralize a full-screen square in any screen size

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment, flexbox

The problem is simple:

- The main part of my page is a square that should be shown at the center of the screen in all screen sizes and orientations
- The square should use the screen efficiently and be as big as possible without the need to scroll
- No scrollbars, no fixed sizing, no overflow-hidden, no Javascript.
- Flexbox is encouraged.

This is how the page should look like in a landscape or portrait browser:

[image: The square should be at the center in all conditions]

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DCGJf) as a starting point.

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="square">
    Square
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: related: [Maintain aspect ratio of div but fill screen width and height in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20590239/703717)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's my attempt to achieve the end goal.

The key point is to use [`vmin` viewport percentage length](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) for both `width` and `height` properties of the square box:

**[Example Here](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/lgjsr)**

```css
.body, .square {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.square {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
}
```

*(vendor prefixes omitted for brevity, check the "Compiled View" in the [demo](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/lgjsr)).*

Comment: For those not interested in [CSS Flexbox Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/), here is **[an alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/fp0n5nLe/)** which is supposed to work on IE9 as well.