# Keep content div aspect ratio with fixed height header

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to create an image slideshow with a fixed ratio of 4:3, filling the whole viewport on a website with a fixed height header of 80px. How can I accomplish this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css) is pretty close, but it's lacking the fixed header.

Any help?

The layout should be:

```
 -------------------------------------      -
| Header: height = 80px, width = 100% |     |
 -------------------------------------      |
    |          Main div           |         > Total height = 100%
    |      Fixed ratio = 4:3      |         |
    |          Centered           |         |
     -----------------------------          -


|------------------v------------------|
           Total width = 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS does the trick:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
}
article {
    /* Get the height based on the available space (100 height - 80px) */
    height: calc(100vmin - 80px);
    /* Get the width based on the available space and aspect ratio (height /3 * 4) */
    width: calc((100vmin - 80px) / 3 * 4);
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header></header><article></article>
```

Using `calc` we can easily determine that we our bottom box to have a `height` of `100% - 80px`, or `calc(100vmin - 80px)`. From there, we can calculate the `width` of the object using the same calculation. I'm using `vmin` to account for behaviour on portrait screens.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That does work, except when the window height is larger than width, in which case it overflows the div instead of keeping it all in view.

Comment: @fseixas I have amended it to use `vmin`, which negates this problem by giving me the lowest common denominator between the height and width of the viewport.

Comment: That does improve it, it is now resizing the height in this case, but there's still some overflow to the left, ie, width>vw.

Comment: Hmmm I see what you mean. You could add a `max-width` at that point and say it shouldn't be wider than `100%` (or `100vw`) even though its actually cheating.

Comment: Yes, but while that cheat would prevent the overflow, it would not keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: Thats why i called it a cheat. Theres just some things where cutting off 20 pixels wont make the difference. Ah well, i did my best. Cheers

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot anyway, I will use your solution for now.