# html5 video 100% width & height via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, responsive-design

How can I achieve something like this http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-agency/ ?

Basically it is a responsive video that fit whole dimension of the screen.
I tried but without success, my problem is that the video doesn't fit the whole screen size (like the reference website)

I saw that site and I think I have to use javascript to give the dimensions

this is my test on codepen http://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/YyawvO

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      function setHeight() {
        windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();

        $('.video-wrap, video').css('height', windowHeight);
        $('.video-wrap, video').css('width', windowWidth);

      }

      setHeight();

      $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
      });
    });
```

Many thanks

Comment: You just want video not that flip effect?

Comment: You have to crop the video, or in other words keep the ratio of the video, and fit the width/height missing the most, and let the rest overflow the screen, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v9nwmqr3/**

Comment: @NenadVracar I don't want the flip effect, I would like to have that video responsive and adapt to the screen size.

Comment: thanks @adeneo, have you seen the website? it seems that the video is more responsive, your code seems that crop the video

Comment: I've seen the website, and it does crop the video, that's the only way to keep the ratio and make it overflow that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain aspect ratio of div but fill screen width and height in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of this plugins

http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/

https://github.com/matthojo/videojs-Background

If you don't have previous experience working with plugins just remember to include `jquery` script **before** plugin script

Comment: thanks, but I prefer don't use a plugin only for these scope, I think it is not a massive issue, but at the moment I can't figure how can I do.

Comment: I highly recommend using plugin for this but you decide.