# CSS: placing a container with defined proportions as huge as possible on the window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to solve the following problem with CSS:

I have a container, say it's a div. It should be always visible on my page, vertically and horizontally centered.
The container should not have a fixed size, but a fixed proportion (or aspect ratio), say: "width = 1/3 of height".
Moreover, the container should be always visible as huge as possible. (Meaning either "touch" the upper and lower OR the left and right borders of the browser window, depending on the current window size)

This is how I proceeded so far:

**relevant html:**

```
<body>
    <div>Text</div>
</body>
```

**css:**

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
}

div {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: red;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This of course only centers the div. The cucial part is the sizing, that I described above. Would this be possible with css?

Comment: So you want `width = 1/3 of height`?

Comment: yes.. the div should always stay in this proportion. at the same time filling the window as much as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain aspect ratio of div but fill screen width and height in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css)

Comment: yes, thanks for the link. this is the same thing that I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `min-height: 100vh` so element will always be full height and  `width: calc(100vh/3);` so width is `1/3` of window height

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/417/)**

```css
body {
   margin: 0px;
}

div {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: red;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   min-height: 100vh;
   width: calc(100vh/3);
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

Comment: cool, goes in the right direction. but is not yet exactly what I need. Let's use the proportion (width = 0.8 * height) for testing. So I resize the window vertically: After the point the window has the same size as the box, I get scrollbars - which I want to avoid. In this case I'd like the div to shrink and see whitespace above and below it.

Comment: You can change `width` with media queries.

Answer (score -1):

This is a version of the [responsive video solution](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php).  You'll need to wrap the element you want to keep the ratio for in a container.

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    padding-top:33%;
    width:100%;
}

#container div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Padding (and margin) percentages are based on the width of the element.  So, if the width is 100%, the height in the above code will be 1/3 of the width (33%).

Comment: Yes. If you want height, you'll have to use the `vh` units which are only relative to the viewport height or use javascript to calculate the ratios.

Comment: yes, this is width only. I want to avoid the JS solution, if possible. could you show an example with the vh units?

Comment: @fauxserious At least currently this does not answer the question, as it is width-only.

Comment: `The container should not have a fixed size, but a fixed proportion (or aspect ratio), say: "width = 1/3 of height"`