# CSS to create element with fixed ratio

Tags: css, centering, aspect-ratio

I want to create an HTML page with:

- A fixed-width, full-height Navigation pane on the left
- A square element in the centre of the remaining area

I want this square to be as big as possible, expanding to fill the area not taken up by the navigation pane.

I have a JavaScript solution for this (see below and as a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymzq6zm0/1/)), but I'm hoping that it is possible to do this as a CSS only solution.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    nav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 96px;
      background-color: #666;
    }
    main {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>  
</head>

<body>
<nav>
  Navigation
</nav>

<main>
  This should be square
</main>

<script>
;(function createSquareArea() {
  var main = document.querySelector("main")
  var nav = document.querySelector("nav")
  var navWidth = nav.getBoundingClientRect().width
  var debounceDelay = 100
  var timeout

  window.onresize = windowResized
  maintainRatio()

  function windowResized() {
    if (timeout) {
      window.clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
    timeout = window.setTimeout(maintainRatio, debounceDelay)
  }

  function maintainRatio() {
    timeout = 0

    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight
    var mainWidth = window.innerWidth - navWidth
    var minDimension = Math.min(windowHeight, mainWidth)

    var left = (mainWidth - minDimension) / 2 + navWidth
    var top = (windowHeight - minDimension) / 2

    main.style.left = left + "px"
    main.style.top = top + "px"
    main.style.width = minDimension + "px"
    main.style.height = minDimension + "px"
  }
})()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is different from the [Maintain Aspect Ratio question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css) that you linked to, in that it requires a vertical navigation pane, so viewport units cannot be used directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ymzq6zm0/7/

HTML

```
<nav>
  Navigation
</nav>

<main>
  <div class="sc">
    This should be square
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
   html, body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
    }
    nav {
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: 96px;
      background-color: #666;
    }
    main {
      float: left;
      width: calc(100% - 96px);
      height: 100vmin;
      max-height: calc(100vw - 96px);
    }
    .sc {
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      height: 100vmin;
      width: 100vmin;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: calc(100vw - 96px);
    }
```

### How it works

Our **main** objective here is to:

- Center align `.sc`
- Align `.sc` vertically center
- Make sure `.sc` is always a sqaure
- Make `.sc` responsive

The square is highly responsive as it changes its height and width according to the window's or view port's height and width. We need to use `vw` (viewport's width) and `vmin` (lowest value between viewport's height and width). Read more about these units here: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

To make `.sc` a square, we need to make sure its width and height are always equal. Since the ratio of height and width of viewport is not always the same, we need to find out the lowest value between these two and assign them to `.sc` which can be done using the `vmin` unit mentioned above.

*The square should always remain centered in the remaining area after the navigation on the left, never cross the remaining area and resize accordingly.*

This can be accomplished the following codes:

```
    nav {
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: 96px;
      background-color: #666;
    }
    main {
      float: left;
      width: calc(100% - 96px);
      height: 100vmin;
      max-height: calc(100vw - 96px);
    }
    .sc {
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      height: 100vmin;
      width: 100vmin;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: calc(100vw - 96px);
    }
```

`main` is the remaining area after nav. We make sure of this by using the `calc` property to subtract the `nav` width from 100%.

The `.sc` is placed inside `main` and we have added the extra `max-width` and `max-height` properties to make sure `.sc` always resizes itself according to `main`.

`max-height: calc(100vw - 96px);` property of `.sc` is always equal to `width: calc(100% - 96px);` property of `main`. They both calculate the same values.

By adding `max-width: 100%;` to `.sc` we make sure it's maximum width is equal to that of `main`.

Now since, both the `max-height` and `max-width` along with width and height of `.sc` remain the same, it will always be a square.

At the end we put both `nav` and `main` inside `.wrapper` which is a flexbox and has `align-items: center;` property. This will ensure that the square is always vertically centered with respect to the `nav`.

Comment: Almost — but if the window is tall then the square is cut off on the right.

Comment: @JamesNewton I have updated the answer to make sure the box is always a square.

Comment: Nice! Now the box is always a square, but it's not centred vertically on a tall page.

Comment: @JamesNewton I have updated to make it work exactly the way you want it.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your persistence in getting it to work.

Comment: @JamesNewton no problem. I am happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with viewport units.

**HTML**

```
<div class='page-wrapper'>
  <nav>

  </nav>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='square'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html
{
  height: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper
{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #444;
}

.content
{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.square
{
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #111;
  max-width: calc( 100vw - 200px );
  max-height: calc( 100vw - 200px );
}
```

See this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ryannwarner/hugt40cm/

Comment: This gives a square with a fixed size of 200 x 200 pixels. The square does not adjust its size to fill the available area when you resize the window.

Comment: I went an extra level deep. It's parent, `<div class='content'>` is resizing to fill all remaining space.

Comment: Your `.content` div is not necessarily square.

Comment: I see your point, I've updated my fiddle.

Comment: Now, if the window is not wide enough, the square overlaps the Navigation pane

Comment: I updated my answer to prevent the square from overlapping using calc().

Answer (score 0):

Viewport units and `calc` can do a lot of this but I'm not sure on your final desired result.

If you want both dimension to recalculate you *will* need javascript.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 96px;
  background-color: #666;
}
main {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 96px;
  height: calc(100vw - 96px);
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vw - 96px);
  max-width: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  Navigation
</nav>

<main>
  This should be square
</main>
```

[**JSfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ymzq6zm0/5/) with no `max-height`...I think you can see the problem with a CSS method.

Comment: Your green element remains a square, but it is always flush to the edge of the Navigation pane, rather than centred.

Comment: How much space do you want...you haven't stated. It's just a matter of adjusting the calc values to adjust for any spacing. As I said, we don't know what this is supposed to look like. In any case, if the size is determined by *either* height **or** width (whichever is smaller) you will need js to calculate.

Comment: I provided a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymzq6zm0/1/) that shows exactly how I want this to behave.

Comment: No...you showed a rectangle...not a square. Making the square is simple enough but you haven't stated any min/max requirements as to size. The fiddle is unclear there.

Comment: The black **square** in my jsFiddle is always as tall and as wide as possible. If the white rectangle that contains it is tall, then the square is the full width. If the white rectangle is wide, then the square is the full height. The square is "as big as possible, expanding to fill the area not taken up by the navigation pane." Are you seeing something different?