# How do i make a div/box responsive to the width and height of the screen?

Tags: html, css

also make it so it'll always be centered horizontally and vertically, and the width will always be `1.5x` bigger than the height. here is an illustration.
The height on my code is not responsive.

html

```
<body>
    <div id='box'></div>
</body>
```

css

```css
body{
  border: 3px solid black;
}
#box{
   border: 3px solid red;
   width:60vw;
   height: 40vw;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: code is <div id='box'></div> .. you get the idea.

Comment: I "get the idea" that you haven't read the Stack Overflow help docs on how to ask an appropriate question. Are you expecting someone to just write the code for you?

Comment: well that's all the code i've got.. i didn't think i would need to post it up since its only a div with a box id. sorry if i didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: You should try to accomplish your task yourself, researching as much as you can, then come here to get help on specific problems. There isn't much to go off of here, unfortunately.

Comment: yes of course. thanks for the help

Comment: Markup sure appears responsive here... perhaps the issue is with your *testing* methods... not the markup??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain aspect ratio of div but fill screen width and height in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css)

Comment: showdev, thank you so much for pointing me to this post, exactly what i was looking for. i did some research but didn't know what the keywords are. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you can go with your styles and `flexbox` like demonstrated in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s1rsjbn2/
to have your #box full width on the two screens that look like tablet and mobile just use a media query to set

```
#box{width:100vw;height:66.666667vw;}
```