# Div that fits into parent and maintains an aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, css-position, aspect-ratio

I've got a `div` element that maintains an aspect ratio: it calculates its height based on its width (using the padding trick). What I'd like to do is to put this `div` into another one by fitting the maximum space available, vertically and horizontally, no crop. I think the closest thing to what I want is the `object-fit: contain` - which is `img` only.

I want the div to cover the max height and width possible while maintaining the aspect ratio. No vertical or horizontal crop.

Is it even possible with CSS only? If so, how?

Update:
A good [article](https://www.bram.us/2017/06/16/aspect-ratios-in-css-are-a-hack/) where things are at the moment.

code (Can be any other solution, doesn't have to be built on this snippet):

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="embed">
    this should accommodate all the available space and maintain aspect ratio, no crop when width is too wide
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `width:100%;` ?

Comment: add your code please!

Comment: @Adam - code added

Comment: you want the div to cover `100%` of the screen?

Comment: No. I want the div to cover the max height and width possible while maintaining the aspect ratio. No vertical or horizontal crop.

Comment: Your code seem to fulfill your needs, i don't understand what you want, Or you want to remove the (padding trick) and achieve this in some other way ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa It does partially fulfil my needs: maintains aspect ratio BUT does not care about height. It crops vertically instead of behaving like a max-height was set.

Comment: Okay i don't understand the end goal here, so if you don't mind include a preview of how you want it to be with all the constraints.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Illustration added.

Comment: `I want the div to cover the max height and width possible while maintaining the aspect ratio` Seems Impossible to maintain the aspect ratio if you want it to stretch on both sides.

Comment: I want to stretch until one of the sides reaches its max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it looks like it can't be solved by CSS only. If anyone interested, I've put together a [React component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contain) that does the job (Tests and better README soon, when I have time).

It wraps its children into a `div` and uses JavaScript to compute the width and height of that div in order to accommodate the available space while maintains the given aspect ratio. It basically stretches the wrapper until one of the sides reaches its maximum.

**BREAKING UPDATE** a [CSS only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css/36295495#20593342) has been found!

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your "BREAKING UPDATE" is based on the viewport width/height, not that of the parent element.

Answer (score 12):

[aspect-ratio](https://web.dev/aspect-ratio/) with `overflow:hidden` on Chromium 88, <strike>Firefox 87</strike> , and <strike>Safari Technology Preview 118</strike> is your friend.

### Update January 2023:

Now you'll need a `@container (aspect-ratio > X)` container query too. Firefox `v110.0b2`, Safari and Chromium all pass.

I updated the code below, also [the demo on jsitor](https://jsitor.com/DNjTXHLpmu).

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  container-type: size;
  container-name: resize-box;
  display: grid;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: black 2px solid;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

.embed {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px red solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

@container resize-box (aspect-ratio > 1/1) {
  .embed {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.embed > div {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="embed">
    <div>1:1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution. I'm surprised it hasn't been selected or received any other upvotes until now.

Comment: This no longer works on Microsoft Edge 108.0.1462.54 :/

Comment: @Vapid indeed – in Chrome too! Good find – need to investigate…

Comment: @Vapid I updated the solution. Should work again on Chromium (including Edge) and also on Safari. Could you try it?

Comment: Container queries solves this problem like no other. I've been hitting my head against the wall for weeks, until I saw this gem here.

Answer (score 4):

The only workaround I managed to achieve so far is to wrap the child element in to svg's [foraignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) tag:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.style.height = container.style.height === '100px' ? '200px' : '100px';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}


#container {
  background-color: #ffceaf;
  width: 400px;
}

svg {
  background-color: #b8d6ff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Change parent height</button>

<div id="container" style="height: 100px;">
  <svg width="15000" height="5000">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
      <div id="content">
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
        content content content content content content content
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>
```

This solution has downsides:

- Browser compatibility (IE/Edge do not support foraignObject properly)
- It's not a best practice. Including elements from a different XML namespace may cause futher issues(?).

I feel like using JS might be better option here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my CSS-only solution:

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/benaloney/pen/OJwLZja?editors=1100) or run demo here ⬇

```css
.resizable-container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 330px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aspect-thing {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  border: 2px red solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable-container"> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="aspect-thing">
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<p>Resize me ^</p>
```

[image]

Comment: excellent solution. but i also want to align the child div vertical center. i cant find a solution, so i instead compute the div's width and height by js manually and use flex to align center.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it is pure css.
It uses nested flexboxes. The **outer** is `flex-direction: row` and the **inner** is `flex-direction: column`. It is important the inner also has to have aspect-ratio is set to 1/1 and notice that **inner**'s *height* is set and **inner:before**'s *width* is set.

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an improvement on [Ben Winding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419584/ben-winding)'s solution that centers the div vertically:

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/nick-tiut/pen/RwOPBdB) or run demo here ⬇

```css
:root {
  --aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  --container-max-width: 90%;
}

.resizable-container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 330px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: var(--container-max-width);
  margin: auto; 
  display: flex;
}

.inner-container {
  flex-grow: 1; 
  align-self: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; 
  aspect-ratio: var(--aspect-ratio);
}

.aspect-thing {
  aspect-ratio: var(--aspect-ratio);
  border: 2px red solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable-container"> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="aspect-thing">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<p>Resize me ^</p>
```