# How to make div element auto-resize maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a `div` centered in the screen. This div should have a specific `width` and `height` when it fits in the available window space, but it should shrink to fit when the available window space is not enough, but also, maintaining its original aspect ratio.

I've been looking at lots of examples that work for a decreasing `width`, but none that work for both `width` and `height` changes in the window size.

Here's my current CSS:

```
* {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.stage_wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: gray;
}
.stage {
    width: 960px;
    height: 540px;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: chocolate;
    object-fit: contain; /* I know this is for images, it's an example of what I'm looking for */
}
```

And, my current HTML:

```
<div class="stage_wrapper">
    <div class="stage">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is showing a centered `div` that has a fixed `width` of 960px and a fixed `height` of 540px. **It should never be bigger than that.**

Then, if I change the size of my window to have a smaller `width` or `height` than that, the `div` element is successfuly shrinking - except it is not maintaining the original aspect ratio, and that is what I'm looking for. I want it to respond to changes in both `width` and `height`.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `aspect-ratio` <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#ratios)</sup> property has a good support now so you can use the below:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gray;
}


.stage {
  --r: 960 / 540;

  aspect-ratio: var(--r);
  width:min(90%, min(960px, 90vh*(var(--r))));
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  
  background: 
    /* this gradient is a proof that the ratio is maintained since the angle is fixed */
    linear-gradient(30deg,red 50%,transparent 50%),
    chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

---

**Old answer**

Here is an idea using viewport unit and `clamp()`. It's a kind of *if else* to test if the width of the screen is bigger or smaller than the height (considering the ratio) and based on the result we do the calculation.

In the code below with have two variables `cv` and `ch` and only one of them will be equal to `1`

- If it's `cv` then the width is bigger so we set the height to `cv` and the width will be based on that height so logically `cv/ratio`
- If it's `ch` then the height is bigger so we set the width to `cv` and the height will be based on that width so logically `ch/ratio`

In the `clamp()` I am using `1vh`/`1vw` that I multiple by `90` which is equivalent to your `90%` to have `90vh`/`90vw`

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gray;
}


.stage {
  --r: calc(960 / 540);
  
  --cv: clamp(0px,(100vw - 100vh*var(--r))*10000,1vh);
  --ch: clamp(0px,(100vh*var(--r) - 100vw)*10000,1vw);

  height: calc((var(--cv) + var(--ch)/var(--r)) * 90 );
  width:  calc((var(--ch) + var(--cv)*var(--r)) * 90 );
  
  max-width: 960px;
  max-height: 540px; /* OR calc(960px/var(--r)) */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  
  background: 
    /* this gradient is a proof that the ratio is maintained since the angle is fixed */
    linear-gradient(30deg,red 50%,transparent 50%),
    chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

In theory the clamp can be simplified to:

```
--cv: clamp(0px,(1vw - 1vh*var(--r)),1vh);
--ch: clamp(0px,(1vh*var(--r) - 1vw),1vw);
```

But to avoid any rounding issue and to not fall into values like `0.x` I consider a big value to make sure it will always be clamped to `1` if positive

**UPDATE**

It seems there is a bug with Firefox so here is another version of the same code:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gray;
}


.stage {
  --r: calc(960 / 540);
  
  --cv: clamp(0px,(100vw - 100vh*var(--r))*100,90vh);
  --ch: clamp(0px,(100vh*var(--r) - 100vw)*100,90vw);

  height: calc((var(--cv) + var(--ch)/var(--r)) );
  width:  calc((var(--ch) + var(--cv)*var(--r)) );
  
  max-width: 960px;
  max-height: 540px; /* OR calc(960px/var(--r)) */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  
  background: 
    /* this gradient is a proof that the ratio is maintained since the angle is fixed */
    linear-gradient(30deg,red 50%,transparent 50%),
    chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you so much! This kind of CSS is really new to me. Do you know what kind of backwards compatibility I can expect from it?

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo I think only IE will have issue with my code which is not a surprise but you should have no issue with other browsers. clamp and CSS variables are well supported now.

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is really clever! I'm having a bit of trouble following the code though. Could you elaborate on what `--cv` and `--ch` are? Even defining the full names of the variables would help. Thanks!

Comment: @LandonSchropp I am already detailing what are both variables :) .. the name is irrelevant, I can call them `a` and `b`. You simply need to understand the logic I am detailing.

Comment: @TemaniAfif You don't say anywhere in your post what the `--cv` and `--ch` variables represent. Why did you choose those names? What do they mean? I'm trying to understand your logic, but it's difficult because you don't explain *why* you choose those variables. It would be easier with clear names for your variables. https://medium.com/coding-skills/clean-code-101-meaningful-names-and-functions-bf450456d90c

Answer (score 3):

Any solution using `vw` & `vh` assumes your container is the viewport. But what if you need an element that letterboxes to fit *any* container?

In other words, you want the behavior of `object-fit: contain` for an element that's not an `<img>` or `<video>`.

You need a container that centers both vertically and horizontally:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

and a contained object with fixed `aspect-ratio` that stretches either its `width` or `height` to `100%`:

```css
#object {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  overflow: hidden;
  [dimension]: 100%;
}
```

where `[dimension]` is `width` if the container is tall, and `height` otherwise.

If you don't know ahead of time whether it's going to be tall or not, a little javascript is needed to check for tallness and decide which dimension to stretch.

```js
function update() {
  const isTall = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight < aspectRatio;
  object.style.width = isTall ? '100%' : 'auto';
  object.style.height = isTall ? 'auto' : '100%';
}

new ResizeObserver(update).observe(container);
```

I don't think this dimension switching can be accomplished in pure CSS without javascript.

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/drskot/0to62p9b/140/).

Answer (score 1):

You can set your height and width like:

```
  height: 80vw;
  width: 80vw;
```

Then, you can set the max height and width like:

```
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vh;
```

Or if you have other things like headers in the way then:

```
  max-height: calc(100vh - 32px);
  max-width: calc(100vh - 32px);
```

The 32px is how many pixels(or other measurements) it takes up

Answer (score -1):

Use this CSS maybe:

```
.stage_wrapper {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background: gray;
```

}

```
.stage {
width: 50vw;
height: 40vw;
max-width: 90%;
max-height: 90%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background: chocolate;
object-fit: contain; /* I know this is for images, it's an example of what I'm looking for */
```

}

You can adjust the code if you want to to be bigger or smaller, but this will let your div have a fixed aspect ratio.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when decreasing the height of the window only.