# How does width/height get calculated on position:absolute container with text in it and width:auto;height:auto?

Tags: html, css

The following example shows a `position:absolute` element centered on screen, with `width:auto` and `height:auto`, yet it has some particular width to height ratio of approximately `2.909090909090909` no matter what size your viewport is.

How is this constant ratio determined?

```css
body,
html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

div {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-size: 3vw;
font-family: sans-serif;
background: pink;
width: auto; height: auto
}
```

```html
<div>
You are in! The pill you took is part of a trace program. It's designed to disrupt your input/output carrier signal so we can pinpoint your location.
</div>
```

Comment: related if you want to really control the ratio yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864592/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we turn off `top` and `transform`, this is how it looks:

[image]

Then, the block is moved to the center (using those `top` and `transform`), but its width is determined by the "squeeze" caused by `left` (remember that it's a div, so by default it wants to be 100% of the parent's width).

It means that the amount of "squeezing" is dependent on the screen width.

The thing is `font-size` **is also dependent on the screen width**: `3vw`.

Since both the box's width and the font size is calculated by the width of the container (which is in this case, the same size as the viewport itself), you get that constant size.

If you had a constant font size, let's say of `2rem`, this is how it will look:

[image]

Comment: Oh, interesting: it automatically expands if it has any inline items (f.e. text), but if it only has block items then it shrinks to their size. Huh! Thanks!