# Full bleed responsive image with overlay div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to solve something that looked pretty straightforward at the beginning, but has developed into a little nightmare.
I was able to code parts of the functionality described below, but not all together.

I have images as DataURLs on a website. Dimensions and aspect ratios of these images are variable.
I want to create some kind of lightbox with the following characteristics (see scheme):

- `IMG` (or `DIV`) with preserved aspect ratio (like `object-fit: contain;` or `background-image: contain;`)

  - responsive
  - nearly full screen with ~1em margin
  - horizontally and vertically centered
- a `DIV` exactly overlying that `IMG` (or `DIV`) as container for blending a result image
- another exactly overlying `DIV` as container for corner texts
- as background canvas a full view port `DIV` (`position: fixed; inset: 0;` behaviour) with elevated brightness and backdrop-filter

[image]

I tried all of the related methods suggested here, but was not able to get the whole functionality.
Is there any way to do this with HTML/CSS? Is there a (simple) way to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: this can probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864592/8620333

Comment: Thank you! I will try to solve it with the clamp() method.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for your suggestion! I was able to create a working solution with `clamp`: https://jsfiddle.net/m34z6uL2/5/ 
However, this is not working in Firefox (works in Android, Chrome, Opera). Any idea why?

Comment: it's seems there is an issue with Firefox (even with my answer). Will try to figure out why

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/hu4mLndb/1/ I changed the formula slightly so it can work on firefox

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Thank you! It is getting better. Still, there is some issue when resizing the view port to a certain breakpoint (height or width), the stage will shrink down to nearly zero.

Comment: Any other ideas how to solve my problem? 
@TemaniAfif suggestion works, but there are some issues with large screen sizes, especially in Firefox.

Comment: So this is my final solution now: http://jsfiddle.net/04af5rmc/10/

I use Javascript to pass the aspect-ratio of the image to CSS. I adapted the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590239/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-div-but-fill-screen-width-and-height-in-css. There are 2 different settings, 1 for landscape, and 1 for portrait images.

This works in most browsers and has no screen size issues.