# link height of img to img width to maintain square ratio during screen resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I have a set of thumbnail images whose width resizes with the size of the screen. They have a max-width but the height is unstated at present. The images all end up having the same width but differing heights which is half correct.

Essentially I would like them to be contained within a square and as the width changes then the height should change to be the same as the width with the image inside adjusting itself to maintain the aspect ratio. I currently have a set max-height and max-width but that doesn't maintain a 1:1 ratio of the container. The images themselves are not square.

The idea is that I will have multiple images next to each other. If I am not mistaken css vars cannot be tied to variables that haven't been expressly declared. SO to use javascript?

```css
.product-single__thumbnail-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 123px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <img class="product-single__thumbnail-image" src="//someting.jpeg">
</li>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65864203/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey did u mean something like this?
i used javasrcipt tho so i dont know if it counts as an aswer to ur question sry

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #image {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100%;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEkn.png" alt="" id='image'>
  </div>
  <script>
    const image = document.getElementById('image')
    image.height = `${image.width}`
    window.addEventListener('resize',()=>{
      image.height = `${image.width}`
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```