# Letterboxing content with a given aspect ratio purely with CSS

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I know about two ways to grow an element to the largest size with a given aspect ratio (in the codepens, note and play with the resize handles):

- [The old padding trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/), also [see my codepen here](https://codepen.io/jth42/pen/jOVYMQL) and
- the newer [single-celled-grid-with-svg-sidekick trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratios-svg/), also [see my codepen here](https://codepen.io/jth42/pen/wvopzRo).

Both solutions work by letting the height be determined by the given width and the aspect ratio.

Both solutions fail when

- I don't have enough height to give and really want the content vertically letterboxed (with space left and right) or
- I do have more than enough height and I still want the content horizontally letterboxed (with space top and bottom).

A typical example would be a viewer window of a fixed size displaying and image of a different size.

This is easy to do in JS, but of course a pure CSS solution would be preferable.

[This codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/letterboxing-in-js-and-css-26tii?file=/src/index.tsx) shows what I would want to have, implemented in JS.

There are special solutions: `svg` has `preserveAspectRatio`, and `img` and `video` have `object-fit` (video is quite cool actually because it allows you to position the chrome independently from the video; if you want to play with a sample [I have one here](https://codepen.io/jth42/pen/abBEBwe)).

So - how do I get that for arbitrary html?

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864592/8620333 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif It appears to be limited to the case where I actually know the content's size (either hard-coding it as he did or again with JS) and also the example refers to screen size units, making it unclear if this would even work in a box. I had a little bit of unsuccessful fiddling with it, but so far I think it's yet another special case.

Comment: you don't need to know the content size. All you have to know is the ratio (the max values aren't mandatory if you don't want them)

Comment: in the old fashion ways you also had `absolute` positionning *(and `margin:auto`)* to preserve a ratio img :  here an exemple  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LYbexQO with svg from your codepen

Comment: @TemaniAfif I had another look at it, but I can't get this to work. It seems you necessarily need to refer to both the outer width and height in the same calculation and that works with screen units (`vw` and `vh`), but not in relation to arbitrary parent boxes which would need to use percent values. If you can make this work, please show me.