# Constrain div to container width and height with fixed aspect ratio

Tags: css

Let's say I have a container that looks like this:

```
<div class="playing-card">
  <p>Ace of Spades</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is style the `playing-card` container to always have an aspect ratio of `5 / 7`. If the container is too short, I want the playing card to be constrained by its height. If the container is too narrow, then the playing card should be constrained by its width.

[image]

Is something like this possible with CSS? I know this can be done with `object-fit` on replaced elements (such as images and videos), but my actual use case specifically needs to be a div with normal HTML content.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864592/8620333

Comment: padding with `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Are you replacing text on the paragraph with a background image of the card? Can you post the styling you're using already?

Comment: @NathanDawson The HTML I posted here is just a trivial example. The actual container that I need to resize is full of a bunch of HTML. It's not actually a playing card.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think that question was what I was looking for! Thanks for sharing.