# min-height and min-width should always be equal

Tags: html, css

I'm using `min-height` and `min-width` on a div that will be filled dynamically. Is there a way to ensure that the width will always be the same as the height (square), using css?

Comment: In that case don't you want `width` and `height` to be equal, not `min-width` and `min-height`, or is there more to this question?

Comment: It doesn't look like it can be done with only CSS: take a gander at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445536/899126) though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311068/scale-a-div-to-fit-in-window-but-preserve-aspect-ratio for possible CSS-only solutions.

Comment: @Nit I need it to expand dynamically, which is impossible to do with a fixed `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vertical margin or padding with % values, it will takes parent width as reference.

basicly:`<div id="ratio1-1"> <div>content</div></div>` and for CSS

```
#ratio1-1 {
width:80%;
}
#ratio1-1:before {
display:inline-block;
padding-top:100%;/* equals width of its tag parent */
content:'';
}
#ratio1-1 > div {
display:inline-block;
max-width:95%;/ preserve it to fall under pseudio-element */
}
```

You can even `vertical-align pseudo-element` and `div` to `top, center, bottom` or whatever else value you want to play with.

here an example wih another ratio used to fit to image background ratio and content vertical aligned : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/letdh

root tag can be displayed as table and pseudo and child displayed as table-cell;, pseudo takes 0 for width.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't seem to work. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2GAL/1/). Please give a look and tell me what I can do.

Comment: well, if i follow the example, it seems to work to me :) http://jsfiddle.net/b2GAL/2/

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible to assure this using CSS, but you can use JavaScript:

If you need the `min-width` and `min-height` in particular and want to make them the same, you can use:

```
var mheight = document.getElementById('divID').style.minHeight;
var mwidth = document.getElementById('divID').style.minWidth;
if (mheight !== mwidth) {
    mheight = mwidth + 'px';
}
```

However, if you want to make sure that the `width` is always equal to the `height`, you should use `offsetWidth`:

```
var height = document.getElementById('divID').offsetHeight;
var width = document.getElementById('divID').offsetWidth;
if (height !== width) {
    document.getElementById('divID').style.height = width + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted your code, but I think you're barking up the wrong tree with min-width and min-height. I see @GCyrillus has posted a similar solution, but here's another way to achieve this with css using percentages:

http://jsfiddle.net/6N2MW/

```
<div class="square"></div>

.square {
    width: 75%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    outline: solid 1px red;
}
```

You might want to add `overflow: hidden;` or `visible` to suit. This will not adjust to fit content, just based on relative container size.

Comment: my answer allows to insert content ;) , but yes the point is the vertical margin/padding in % taking parents width as reference. pseudo-element is child of it's own tag, so this is why it takes 100%.

Comment: As you say, hence the shout out, also the +1 now :)  I tend to use this solution with absolutely positioned images or video to keep responsive aspect ratio, so content size is not usually relevant.