# `background-size` CSS property not working for html <image> tags

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

It works fine if I set the image source as a CSS `background-image` property, but it breaks altogether if I set the image source via HTML. Why?

```css
.image1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.image2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://i.istockimg.com/cms/resources/images/HomePage/Tiles/EN_US/EN_US_2016_05/ExtendedHuman82598767.jpg');
}
```

```html
<img class="image1" src="http://i.istockimg.com/cms/resources/images/HomePage/Tiles/EN_US/EN_US_2016_05/ExtendedHuman82598767.jpg"></img>

<img class="image2"></img>
```

To let this images show correctly no mattery the width/height combination, am I forced to declare their source from CSS?

---

**edit**: not sure what the question downvote was for...I just wanted to know if it was possible to let images be automatically cropped so they can keep their original aspect ration even if you change both their height and width independently. This works flawlessly when using background images, but apparently not with content. Either way, I got my answer now.

Comment: You're positive that this is not a `picture` tag we're talking about?

Comment: As far as I know `background-image` is not the same as `src` attribute. Loosely speaking one is more like a content whereas the other is a background.

Comment: thanks Tomek, corrected code. I meant <img>

Comment: Thanks @Harry, is there any way to set a property similar to background-size on the content then?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do. Why can't you use "src"?

Comment: I used "src" as an HTML attribute on my first example, which is what I'm trying to do. What do you mean?

Comment: Why are you trying to set a background size to something that isn't a background....that's why it's not clear.

Comment: `<img>` is content...backgrounds are styling.

Comment: Because that was the only way I can get an image to act responsively (scale while mantaining aspect ration regardless of the width and height combination). I know the difference between what each is used for, but I saw no other way of showing what I was trying to achieve visually, but with <img>

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912048/how-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-using-html-img-tag?

Comment: It's not a duplicate...I'm trying to scale BOTH height AND width while also keeping aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On browsers other than IE, you can use the `object-fit: cover` instead of `background-size`.

```css
.image1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://i.istockimg.com/cms/resources/images/HomePage/Tiles/EN_US/EN_US_2016_05/ExtendedHuman82598767.jpg');
}
```

```html
<img class="image1" src="http://i.istockimg.com/cms/resources/images/HomePage/Tiles/EN_US/EN_US_2016_05/ExtendedHuman82598767.jpg"></img>

<img class="image2"></img>
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm guessing that if I want to support IE with responsive images, I'm stuck setting images as background-image, correct?

Comment: Background properties to the figure? Could you do a simple example of that to make it clearer?

Comment: @sgarcia, sorry to confuse you with the figure statement. Ignore that as it is not required. If you need IE support then, yes, you would need to use background images or include a polyfill like this: https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/