# Save aspect ratio of the stream in UIWebView

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview, video-streaming, aspect-ratio

In my project I'm using `UIWebView` in order to watch stream which can be accessible through `http://` link. It's working fine but the problem is that stream has 3:4 aspect ratio while my `UIWebView` has 4:3 aspect ratio. Result - stream is stretched all over `UIWebView` rect.

My code of `UIWebView` initialization:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: frame)
webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false
webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
webView.isOpaque = false
webView.backgroundColor = .red
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

addSubview(webView)
```

And my code of building http link for streaming:

```
private func configurateStreamPath(with ip: String) -> String {
    let path = "http:/\(ip):8080"

    return "<img name=\"Cam\" src=\"\(path)\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"100%%\" \" \"alt=\"Live Feed\" style=\"background-color: #000000\" />"
}
```

I understand that I need to work with parameters I'm passing in HTML link but I'm not sure if I do it correctly because none of suggestions I found worked. I tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912048/how-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-using-html-img-tag) link and [that](https://superuser.com/questions/53475/resize-a-photo-in-html-and-keep-aspect-ratio) link.

Any help would be appreciated. Big thanks!